# Is there a software library that can treat a directory tree like an XPath data structure?

Tags: json, directories, data-structure

Is there a software library that can treat a directory tree like an XPath data structure?

It should be something that can use XPath/JSON like instructions to manipulate data structures in the file system with directories as the paths and branches and files as the data objects?